# MVC 5 with $ajax jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a site in mvc 5 having two dropdownlist cascade, but $.ajax presents an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input", which can not find.

This is a Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult ObtieneComunas(string idRegion = "") 
        {
            var contexto = new ConcesionesContext();

            var comunas = (from s in contexto.Comunas where s.idRegion == int.Parse(idRegion) select new { idComuna = s.idComuna, Nombre = s.Nombre }).ToList();

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = comunas,
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                };
            }
```

This is a View with $ajax

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/jscript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#idRegion').change(function () {
                    var idRegion = parseInt($('#idRegion').val());
                    if(!isNaN(idRegion))
                    {
                        var ddComuna = $("#idComuna");
                        ddComuna.empty();
                        ddComuna.append($("<option></option>").val("").html("Selecione Comuna"));

                        $.ajax({
                            url: '@Url.Action("ObtieneComunas", "Account")', 
                            type: 'GET',
                            data: JSON.stringify({ "idRegion": idRegion }),
                            dataType: "application/json",
                            traditional: true,
                            contentType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                alert(data);
                            },
                            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                var test = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
                                var test2 = $.parseJSON(test.d);
                                alert(test2[0].Name);


                            }
                        });
                    }
            });
```

This is error

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input",

Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you miss "});" in your code, this error occurred. I think you have missed "});" in some place in your code. Here I can see, you have forgot to close the }); of document.ready. So put one more }); at the end and then try. This may help you.

Comment: This below it is not in the transcript, but is in my code. I think it may be a bug in mvc 5.